# What are the differences (CPU, runtime, or otherwise) between using pg pool and pgp as a database connection in an express server

Tags: postgresql, connection-pooling, pg-promise

I've created a few apps which utilize a postgres database, but in all of those projects, I've either used the pool or client function from the pg npm package. Recently I came across the pg-promise node package, and was just wondering if there were any drawbacks to using pg-promise over pool or client. I'm just worried about changes in runtime that would affect how many clients the app could service at one time.

Answer (score 0):

[pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) is "*Built on top of [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres)*". You're still using the same pools and clients.

Nothing changes regarding the amount of connections your database will be able to handle, and unless you use a different approach to building your application (like, using transactions instead of not using transactions, or using individual clients instead of pooling), nothing will change regarding the amount of clients your app will be able to serve.